# Can you set an application control bar's color in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, controls

I can't seem to figure out how to set the application control bar's background color in flex 4? It doesn't have the backgroundColor property, and I'm a little stuck. Any help on how you would go by setting the background color for the application control bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a custom Application Skin.  Create the custom skin as a copy of `spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin` and you'll find the section in there that corresponds to the Application Control Bar (lines 73-114).  You can manipulate the color scheme in there.

Answer (score -1):

You should check the applicable styles for the [ApplicationControlBar](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layouts_06.html), and set the colors as you want for the style enumerated.

You could probably be looking at the fillColors style for this component.

Edit:Although the documentation points to Flex 3, the style can still be set as provided since the same is applied to Flex 4 when using the ApplicationControlBar component.

If you are doing the application using Spark, then you can instead use the controlBarContent property of the Spark application class.

[Flex 4 Documentation Link](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/mx/containers/ApplicationControlBar.html)

Comment: the fillColors style is still relevant to Flex 4. It was not deprecated so he could still utilize that style to set the color for the ApplicationControlBar.